# How to pull data from a previous node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've come across a challenge I struggle with to find the right approach for. The information required is in two different nodes but belong to the same information for a device.

The later node contains the target information for the previous node as per picture:[image: XML nodes]

The phone device has two nodes where information over the device is stored, IP Phones and Workstations. Under Workstations the main information is stored with a key that links it to the IP Phones section.

I have the following code:

```
   <?xml version='1.0'?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
       <xsl:template match="/">
         <html>
           <body>
         <table border="1">
           <tr>
             <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
             <td><strong>Software Version</strong></td>
         <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
           </tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY/ENTRY/ENTRY/ENTRY/ENTRY">
         <xsl:if test="@CLASS='Workstation'">
           <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></td>
         <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTE">
           <xsl:if test="@NAME='Managed IP Phone'">
             <xsl:call-template name="Phone_Data">
               <xsl:with-param name="IPPhone" select="VALUE"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <td>.</td>
           </tr>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
       </body>
     </html>
</xsl:template>

  <!-- Additional templates to pull 2nd phone node data. -->
  <xsl:template name="Phone_Data">
  <xsl:param name="IPPhone"/>
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="$IPPhone"/> </td> <!--   -->
<xsl:for-each select="../ENTRY">
  <xsl:if test="@NAME='IP Phones'">
    <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY">
      <xsl:if test="@NAME=$IPPhone">
        <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTE">
      <!-- This is an attribute under the IP Phones - GBADM104_ENTRY  -->
      <xsl:if test="@NAME='Software Version'">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/></td>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Coming from the GBADM104_ENTRY under the ***Workstations*** node, it does not provide me with the information I expected to get from the GBADM104_ENTRY under the ***IP Phones*** node in the screenshot.

As I am a novice, I obviously have made a mistake in the Phone_Data template to target the node with the data I require. I don't know whether or not one could give me suggestions on how to do this the right way please?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generated by DSEdit -->
  <ENTRY NAME="CustomerSite" CLASS="Site">
    <ENTRY NAME="Production" CLASS="Configuration Set">
      <ENTRY NAME="REG6699CIC01" CLASS="Server">
        <ENTRY NAME="IP Phones" CLASS="IP Phones">
          <ENTRY NAME="51948094-c6e6-4fb9-bb76-ba1986c51429" CLASS="IP Phone">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VAD">
              <VALUE>No</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Software Version">
              <VALUE>3.2.7.0198</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call Park">
              <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Status">
              <VALUE>Current</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
              <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="ReloadedLast">
              <VALUE>20140825143741Z</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
              <VALUE>0004F24F4012</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Name">
              <VALUE>GBADM103</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
              <VALUE>1406660976</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
          </ENTRY>
          <ENTRY NAME="51dbb1fe-9957-420a-bfc3-3f4d9bc1b2fc" CLASS="IP Phone">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Software Version">
              <VALUE>3.2.7.0198</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Status">
              <VALUE>Current</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
              <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="ReloadedLast">
              <VALUE>20140912074858Z</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
              <VALUE>0004F2B37167</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Name">
              <VALUE>GBADM104</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
              <VALUE>1410881183</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
          </ENTRY>
          <ENTRY NAME="51eace77-7f6d-467a-bbac-b27329229c53" CLASS="IP Phone">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VAD">
              <VALUE>No</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Software Version">
              <VALUE>3.2.7.0198</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Status">
              <VALUE>Current</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
              <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="ReloadedLast">
              <VALUE>20140814104810Z</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
              <VALUE>0004F24F3E3B</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persistent">
              <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="IP Address">
              <VALUE>10.254.250.61</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Name">
              <VALUE>GBADS201</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
              <VALUE>1406899229</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
    </ENTRY>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Security">
        <VALUE>Minimal</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Call Ringback Timeout">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VQM Collector Periodic Trigger">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Codec Pref">
        <VALUE>0|G.711 mu-law|</VALUE>
        <VALUE>1|G.711 a-law|</VALUE>
        <VALUE>2|G.729AB|</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Active">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Use 486 For Reject">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Emergency Customer Name">
        <VALUE>Regus</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Call Waiting Tone">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Connection Type">
        <VALUE>SIPAddress</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Sync Forward To IC Status">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="IsSupportedRingSets">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP ID Address SYNC">
        <VALUE>Sync Dynamic</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VQM Collector Session">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP Receive Port">
        <VALUE>5060</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Audio Path">
        <VALUE>Always In</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VAD">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Proxy Group">
        <VALUE>3b6b817b-73e5-4db5-b6d5-57eb0f9b26ff</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Override Date Date Top">
        <VALUE>D</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Software Version">
        <VALUE>3.2.7.0198</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Emergency Location Description">
        <VALUE>15305 Dallas Parkway Suite 300, Addison, TX, 75001</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Headset Microphone Gain">
        <VALUE>21</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call Park">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Region Location">
        <VALUE>North America</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Status">
        <VALUE>Current</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Override Date Format">
        <VALUE>D</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Emergency Numbers">
        <VALUE>911</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature URL Dialing">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="DTMF Off Time">
        <VALUE>80</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
        <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VQM Collector Periodic">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="One Touch Voicemail">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Ring Always">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Regional Tone Set">
        <VALUE>Language_Default</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VQM RTCP-XR">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="ExpansionModules">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Call Waiting">
        <VALUE>beep</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Enable Handsfree">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom NumberFirstCID">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Interface Language">
        <VALUE>English_United_States</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Headset Echo-Noise Suppression">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call List">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Override Date Long Format">
        <VALUE>D</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP Session Timeout">
        <VALUE>60</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="ReloadedLast">
        <VALUE>20140905170113Z</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Phone Manufacturer">
        <VALUE>Polycom</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Disable Delayed Media">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Appearances">
        <VALUE>0|Private|USISM010|Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Inbound SIP Security Challenge">
        <VALUE>none</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Call per Station">
        <VALUE>1</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Bus Gain">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="RTP QOS Byte">
        <VALUE>B8</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Call Dialtone Timeout">
        <VALUE>15</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call List Placed">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Password">
        <VALUE>F08470F66758CE835CA9DD495F57E5B433F03937D78CFA01CAC315492D7F167C</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Location NTP Server Overrides DHCP">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Electronic Hookswitch Mode">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Authentication">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Echo Cancellation">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Phone Limits Calls Per Line Key">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Presence">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="TimeZone">
        <VALUE>CST</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Phone Model">
        <VALUE>IP331</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persist Handset Volume">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP Register Interval">
        <VALUE>86400</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MWI Message Light">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Audio Protocol">
        <VALUE>RTP</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="VQM Collector Period">
        <VALUE>20</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Override 24 Hour Clock">
        <VALUE>D</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Headset Sidetone Gain">
        <VALUE>-3</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Use SIP Session Timer">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Media Port Start Range">
        <VALUE>2222</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Dialplan Digitmap Timeout">
        <VALUE>3|1|3|3</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Call Offering Timeout">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="DefaultLabelType">
        <VALUE>Station</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Group Call Pickup">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Syslog Transport">
        <VALUE>1</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
        <VALUE>0004F2A72B5F</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Location Description">
        <VALUE>Colonnade</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Sync DND To IC Status">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Polycom Headset Speaker Gain">
        <VALUE>4</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persistent">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Disable App Logs When Using Syslog">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Location Time Zone Overrides DHCP">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="User Name">
        <VALUE>38bc4dfa7e384f29bb7e62fc24dac94d</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="IP Address">
        <VALUE>10.175.250.106</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Terminate Call Analysis On Connect">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Disconnect on Broken RTP">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Syslog Render Level">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Headset Mode">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="DTMF On Time">
        <VALUE>80</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="DTMF Type">
        <VALUE>RFC2833</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persist Headset Volume">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call List Received">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP QOS Byte">
        <VALUE>Not Set</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Dial On Offhook">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Use Proxy">
        <VALUE>Not Set</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Network Gain">
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Disallow Media Server Passthru">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Directory">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="External Devices Determine Codecs">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Connection Call Warm Down Time">
        <VALUE>5</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Messaging">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="DTMF Payload">
        <VALUE>101</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Handset Echo-Noise Suppression">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Disable Delayed Media reINVITE">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Name">
        <VALUE>USISM010</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persist Handsfree Volume">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="IP3X0 Line 2 Key Function">
        <VALUE>Line2</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Feature Call List Missed">
        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Emergency Outbound ANI">
        <VALUE>19727152000</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Dialplan Digitmap">
        <VALUE>x.T|*T|*905|*90[1-4]x.T</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Allow SIP Registration">
        <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
        <VALUE>1372825753</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
    </ENTRY>
        </ENTRY>
        <ENTRY NAME="Workstations" CLASS="Workstations">
          <ENTRY NAME="GBADM103" CLASS="Workstation">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Security">
              <VALUE>Minimal</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Active">
              <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Counted Licenses">
              <VALUE>I3_LICENSE_BASIC_STATION</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Connection Type">
              <VALUE>SIPAddress</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP ID Address">
              <VALUE>GBADM103</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
              <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed Label">
              <VALUE>GBADM103</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Line">
              <VALUE>sip:GBADM103@192.168.1.203:5060</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Licenses Enabled">
              <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
        <VALUE>0004F2B37157</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed IP Phone">
              <VALUE>51948094-c6e6-4fb9-bb76-ba1986c51429</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
        <VALUE>1410882147</VALUE>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
          </ENTRY>
          <ENTRY NAME="GBADM104" CLASS="Workstation">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Counted Licenses">
              <VALUE>I3_LICENSE_BASIC_STATION</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP ID Address">
              <VALUE>GBADM104</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed Label">
              <VALUE>GBADM104</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Extension">
              <VALUE>903104</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Line">
              <VALUE>sip:GBADM104@192.168.1.204:5060</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
              <VALUE>0004F2B37167</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Persistent">
              <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed IP Phone">
              <VALUE>51dbb1fe-9957-420a-bfc3-3f4d9bc1b2fc</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
              <VALUE>1410881183</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
          </ENTRY>
          <ENTRY NAME="GBADS201" CLASS="Workstation">
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Counted Licenses">
              <VALUE>I3_LICENSE_BASIC_STATION</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Connection Type">
              <VALUE>SIPAddress</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="SIP ID Address">
              <VALUE>GBADS201</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Station Type">
              <VALUE>Workstation</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed Label">
              <VALUE>GBADS201</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="MAC Address">
              <VALUE>UK1058597LT.uk-eire.regus.local</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Managed IP Phone">
              <VALUE>51eace77-7f6d-467a-bbac-b27329229c53</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Date Last Modified">
              <VALUE>1372819315</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
          </ENTRY>
        </ENTRY>
      </ENTRY>
    </ENTRY>
  </ENTRY>
```

Comment: Input picture is pretty, but input XML would be more useful.

Comment: The XML as in the screenshot can be found here: http://tinyurl.com/lnstls4

Comment: You should add the XML as *text* by [**editing your question**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work).

Comment: Also, please prune it and your XSLT to provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I've added the stripped down version of the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here. The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry-by-name" match="ENTRY" use="@NAME" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Software Version</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY/ENTRY/ENTRY/ENTRY[@CLASS='Workstation']">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('entry-by-name', ATTRIBUTE[@NAME='Managed IP Phone']/VALUE)/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME='Software Version']/VALUE"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>.</td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input (corrected for well-formedness!) will produce the following **result**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Software Version</th>
            <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>GBADM103</td>
            <td>3.2.7.0198</td>
            <td>.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>GBADM104</td>
            <td>3.2.7.0198</td>
            <td>.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>GBADS201</td>
            <td>3.2.7.0198</td>
            <td>.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Note the use of *predicates* to select the nodes of interest, and the use of *key* to lookup data from another branch of the XML input.

Comment: Yeah, the (first) mistake was that OP had too many `ENTRY` steps in the `xsl:for-each/@select`: 5 where he should have had 4.  Changing just this will give the table you produced (but your fix included additional stylistic improvements).  I was onto trying to figure what OP intended to do with the `.` Status column when you posted your answer; I think this is plenty for OP, especially given that absence of stated desired output in his question.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Please not that running the original code in Visual studio or IE explorer does not return any data other than the labels Name, Software Version and status. Adding another ENTRY/ to the for-each select statement does return the required data.

Comment: @NiteOwls As I mentioned in my reply, the input that you posted here is **not** well-formed. It contains an extra `</ENTRY>` at the end, and that's almost certainly the reason why this won't run on your real input. -- Other than that, is your question answered?

Comment: Hi Michael, Many thanks for your answer. This is what I was looking for and I'm grateful for your reply. This fully answered my question. Again many thanks!.